# Ionic App Name cannot Start with Number Error

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I change my ionic app name to 2cheap. its return following error. How to resolve it. [image]

Comment: I never used **[this Cordova plugin](https://github.com/blakgeek/cordova-plugin-app-name)** so I don't know if it works or if it's even a good idea, but I guess that could be one option.

Answer (score 1):

You can't solve this, it is a restriction for Cordova projects...
Only thing you could do is give it a name starting with a letter and rename the project in both the android and ios projects.